# If '<selector>' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular2. I have tried to create a component but showing an error.

This is the `app.component.ts` file.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MyComponentComponent } from './my-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <h4>Something</h4>
    <my-component></my-component>
  `,
  directives: [MyComponentComponent]
})
export class AppComponent { name = 'Sam' }
```

This is the component which i want to create.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'my-component',
template: `
    <p>This is my article</p>
`
})

export class MyComponentComponent {

}
```

Showing the two errors:

1. If `my-component` is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If `my-component` is a Web Component then add `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` to the `@NgModule.schemas` of this component to suppress this message.

Please Help.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

Your `MyComponentComponent` should be in `MyComponentModule`.

And in `MyComponentModule`, you should place the `MyComponentComponent` inside the "exports".

Something like this, see code below.

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [],
   exports: [MyComponentComponent],
   declarations: [MyComponentComponent],
   providers: [],
})

export class MyComponentModule {
}
```

and place the `MyComponentModule` in the `imports` in `app.module.ts` like this (see code below).

```
import { MyComponentModule } from 'your/file/path';

@NgModule({
   imports: [MyComponentModule]
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

After doing so, the selector of your component can now be recognized by the app.

You can learn more about it here: https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/feature-modules.html

Comment: if you're still having issues, don't forget to check your selector declared in your component's .ts file. You might have forgotten to add "app-" to the html code when you placed your component in the parent's html file.

Comment: I've had this error caused by the @Input name being incorrect. Very misleading, so remove inputs in your component tag while troubleshooting.

Comment: I am still having issues with this. I am importing MatRadioModule from angular material/radio and the directives in that module are throwing this error.

Comment: This is not longer valid for latest version of Angular (I tested it on v.8)

Comment: another complicated and convoluted issue that makes no intuitive sense. Thanks angular, as always.

Comment: I followed your steps but having the same issue:

app-profile-form' is not a known element (used in the 'ProfilePage' component template):
1. If 'app-profile-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.

Comment: I was told in another Stack post that I don't need the ngModule.  When I remove it I get the error but when I add it the error goes away but I don't see any content on the parent page

Comment: @Jared a useful remark, thx. It brought me the solution to my issue: the selector <app-foo.bar> was generated by cli. After changing it to <app-foo-bar> (note the "." and the "-") my compiler was happy-building.

Comment: what worked for me was adding MyComponentComponent to  imports: [] as well. thanks!

Comment: @Jared 's comment is the reason may day is saved

Answer (score 44):

Maybe This is for name of `html` tag component

You use in `html` something like this `<mycomponent></mycomponent>`

You must use this `<app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>`

Comment: Name of `html` tag determine `selector` property. In this case is `my-component`.

Comment: Worked for me! Was searching for an hour.

Answer (score 33):

are you importing it in your `app.module.ts` like so and remove the directives bit:-

```
@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [MyComponentModule],// or whatever the name of the module is that declares your component.

    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Your `MyComponentModule` should be like this:-

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [MyComponentComponent],
    declarations: [MyComponentComponent],
    providers: [],
})
export class MyComponentModule {
}
```

Comment: You forgot about `exports`

Comment: It helped me as I was able to import and export the 3rd party angular component. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, clear explanation.

Answer (score 17):

In my case I was writing unit tests for a component that uses sub-components, and I was writing tests to make sure those subcomponents were in the template:

```
it('should include the interview selection subview', () => {
    expect(fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('app-interview')))
    .toBeTruthy()  
  });
```

I didn't get an error, but a warning:

> WARN: ''app-interview' is not a known element:
>
> 1. If 'app-interview' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. WARN: ''app-interview' is not a known element:
> 2. If 'app-interview' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 3. If 'app-interview' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>      to suppress this message.'

Also, the subcomponent did *not* show inside the browser during testing.

I used `ng g c newcomponent` to generate all the components, so they were already declared in the appmodule, but *not* the test module that for the component I was spec'ing.

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ EditorComponent,
        InterviewComponent]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Answer (score 10):

Check your selector in your *filename.component.ts*

Using the tag in various html files I would say

```
<my-first-component></my-first-component>
```

Should be

```
<app-my-first-component></app-my-first-component>
```

Example

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-first-component',
  templateUrl: './my-first-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-first-component.component.scss']
})
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Declare your `MyComponentComponent` in `MyComponentModule`
2. Add your `MyComponentComponent` to `exports` attribute of  `MyComponentModule`

mycomponentModule.ts

```
@NgModule({
   imports: [],
   exports: [MyComponentComponent],
   declarations: [MyComponentComponent],
   providers: [],
})

export class MyComponentModule {
}
```

3. Add your `MyComponentModule` to your AppModule `imports` attribute

app.module.ts

```
    @NgModule({
       imports: [MyComponentModule]
       declarations: [AppComponent],
       providers: [],
       bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

**Important** If your still have that error, Stop your server `ctrl+c` from terminal, and run it again `ng serve -o`

Comment: The final step is what I needed on a project I hadn't touched in a while.

After an 'npm install" "ng update" and then "npm update"

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `exports` part explicitly, this step was what I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue, found that the template component tags worked with `<app-[component-name]></app-[component-name]>`. So, if your component is called `mycomponent.component.ts`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    <h4>Something</h4>
    <app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
  `,
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to the tsconfig.json file. write this code under angularCompilerOption:

```
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
     "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
     "strictInjectionParameters": true,
     **"enableIvy": false**
 }
```

Comment: Considering this stops the use of Ivy, one of the most important improvements in Angular for years, I think it warrants at least a mention of why you would do this.

Comment: Don't go this way ☝ Ivy is the new standard for over a year now.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare your MyComponentComponent in the same module of your AppComponent.

```
import { AppComponent } from '...';
import { MyComponentComponent } from '...';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [ AppComponent, MyComponentComponent ],
   bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a component in a Shared module.

The component was loading and worked well but typescript was highlighting the html tag with red line and showed this error message.

Inside this component, I noticed I didn't import a rxjs operator.

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
```

When I added this import the error message disappeared.

**Check all imports inside the component**.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

**Check which module the parent component is being declared in...**

If your parent component is defined in the shared module, *so must your child module.*

The parent component could be declared in a shared module and not the module that is logical based on the file directory structure / naming, even the Angular CLI added it into the wrong module in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular v11 and was facing this error while trying to lazy load a component (`await import('./my-component.component')`) and even if `import` and `export` were correctly set.

I finally figured out that the solution was deleting the separate dedicated module's file and move the module content inside the component file itself.

```
rm -r my-component.module.ts
```

and add module inside `my-component.ts` (same file)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.page.scss'],
})
export class MyComponent {
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [MyComponent],
})
export class MyComponentModule {}
```

Comment: This solution may not work, if you wanted to use this component in more than one place

Answer (score 1):

The above error is produced from Angular 9 onwards as well.
This [book](https://testing-angular.com/testing-components-with-children/#shallow-vs-deep-rendering)  provides a solution.

"The warning suggests CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, but the elements in question are not Web Components. We want Angular to simply ignore the elements. Therefore we use the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA, “a schema that allows any property on any element”.
Adding `schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]` to your respective .spec file removes the error.

```
await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [MyComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
}).compileComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your components.module.ts you should import IonicModule like 
this:

`import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';`

Then import IonicModule like this:

```
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
```

so your components.module.ts will be like this:

````
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {PostComponent} from './post/post.component'
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [PostComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule
  ],
  exports: [PostComponent]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }```
````

Answer (score 0):

### Don't `export **default** class MyComponentComponent`!

Related issue that might fall under the title, if not the specific question:

I accidentally did a...

```
export default class MyComponentComponent {
```

... and that screwed things up too.

Why? VS Code added the import to my module when I put it into `declarations`, but instead of...

```
import { MyComponentComponent } from '...';
```

it had

```
import MyComponentComponent from '...';
```

And that didn't map up downstream, assumedly since it wasn't "really" named anywhere with the default import.

```
export class MyComponentComponent {
```

No `default`. Profit.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late ,but i got the same issue but I rebuild(`ng serve`) the project and the error was gone

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar Problem, but none of the mentioned solutions worked. In the end i realized i have a routing problem:

I thought if i specify my component in the app-routing.module like so:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainComponent } from './pages/main/main.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: MainComponent
  },
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

i would not have to import the MainModule in my AppModule, which is wrong since here only the component gets imported. Any other components declared in MainModule will not be visible which results in the error message you described.

Solution 1:
Import the declaring module
Solution 2:
Lazyload the component like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '', loadChildren: () => import('path_to_your_declaringModule').then(m => m.declaringModule)},
}
```

This works since the whole module gets imported here.

I realize you do not use routing in your example, just posting this for any other person that might use routing and stumbles across this question in search for a solution, like i did.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have generated a new module and a new component in it, but I haven't add some custom written shared modules into `component-name.module.ts`
file and proper routing configurations that should be add into `component-name.routing.module.ts` file. Check with other components for the consistency.

Answer (score 0):

I had different modules apart from app.module for example hom-page.mdule

I forgot to add **Home-page.component to Home-page.module in the declarations section**

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when I renamed a component, I started getting this error. Fixed it after deleting `node_modules` folder and then ran `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm implementing an componnent in AppComponent without Angular Routes, so I should to declarate in the test.

Template AppComponent

```
<div class="main">
   <app-header></app-header>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

AppComponenet Test

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });
```

the errors were:

Error: NG0304: 'app-header' is not a known element (used in the 'AppComponent' component template):

1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.
2. If 'app-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

solution:

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
 beforeEach(async () => {
  await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
      RouterTestingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
      AppComponent, HeaderComponent //Add class missing
   ],
  }).compileComponents();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope you are having `app.module.ts`. 
In your `app.module.ts` add below line-

```
 exports: [myComponentComponent],
```

**Like this:**

```
import { NgModule, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './headerComponent/header.component';
import { HeaderMainComponent } from './component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        HeaderMainComponent,
        HeaderComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        RouterModule,
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [HeaderMainComponent],
    exports: [HeaderComponent],
})
export class HeaderModule { }
```