# Angular5/Karma 'selector' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a small issue with my component. Everything is working fine in my browser without any errors, but the Karma debugger throws some errors and as far as I want to have everything clear  I would like to fix it.

**error:**

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
'dj-menu' is not a known element:
1. If 'dj-menu' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'dj-menu' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

The `<dj-menu>` selector is used in `app.component.html`.

**menu.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'dj-menu',
    template: `<nav>
                        <button mat-button routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</button>
                        <button mat-button routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register</button>
                        <button mat-button routerLink="/profile" routerLinkActive="active">Profile</button>
                        <button mat-button routerLink="/radio">Radio</button>
                   </nav>
`,
    styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
    {...} // only an empty constructor and ngOnInit()
}
```

I have a `MenuComponent` declared in `declarations` in `@NgModule` of **app.module.ts**.

As I said it's working fine in browser, but not in the Karma debugger. So far I tried few answers about similar error (e.g [If '<selector>' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937387/if-selector-is-an-angular-component-then-verify-that-it-is-part-of-this-mod)) but nothing is working.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You should be declaring it in the TestBed in the same way it is declared in app.module.ts (I am presuming you are testing with TestBed?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stub child component when you are testing parent component, For example I have two components one is `app` and another is `dj-menu` then I should mock `dj-menu` in `app` test using code something like below

```
@Component({
selector: 'dj-menu',
  template: '<h1> Some test </h1>'
})

class DjMenuComponentStub{
}
```

And my app component look like this (Which uses `dj-menu`)

```
@Component({
selector: 'app',
  template: '<dj-menu></dj-menu>'
})

class AppComponent{
}
```

While testing app component, angular doesn't know about `dj-menu` you have to tell angular to use stub component by declaring

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ DjMenuComponentStub ]
})
```

Comment: Stubbing presumes he is testing a parent component. You cannot tell from the question what it is he is testing.