# Angular 9 update component inheritance decorator

Tags: angular

In the update process of Angular 8 to Angular 9 the update script add's component decorators to baseclasses. This is documented in https://angular.io/guide/migration-undecorated-classes

In the documented example the selector is set in the base class decorator.

**But how do you proceed if you want two different selectors in child components of the base class component?**

Before:

```
class BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'a-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AMenu extends BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class BMenu extends BaseMenu {}
```

After:

```
@Component(???)
class BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'a-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AMenu extends BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class BMenu extends BaseMenu {}
```

The component decorator expects a 'selector'.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `@Directive` decorator, as specified in the link you posted. `@Directive` doesn't require a selector.

```js
@Directive()
class BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'a-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AMenu extends BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class BMenu extends BaseMenu {}
```

Comment: This causes a lint error "...should end with the suffix Directive". Also extending a component from a directive seems a bit dirty.

Comment: Disabling the lint rules for this part would work as a workaround. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Angular made heavy of decorators and meta-data (@Component, @Directive, @NgModule, ...). This meta-data and decorators are not inherited by the child components. So, you can just use a placeholder selector just to fill it in. See https://blog.bitsrc.io/component-inheritance-in-angular-acd1215d5dd8

```html
@Component({
  selector: 'x-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
class BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'a-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class AMenu extends BaseMenu {}

@Component({
  selector: 'b-menu',
  template: '<div></div>'
})
export class BMenu extends BaseMenu {}
```

Comment: This unfortunately causes a build error "1. If 'a-menu' is an Angular component then verify that it is part of this module."

Comment: Have you checked your NgModule for declarations?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937387/if-selector-is-an-angular-component-then-verify-that-it-is-part-of-this-mod

Comment: Listing the base component in the app.module declarations solved it. As stated in the error. I was not listed originally, because before the update the base class had not decorator. Added a decorator makes it mandatory to add it to the module declarations even if is just used as a base class.