# If 'student-entries' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am creating a table in angular using the following:

```
ng g @angular/material:material-table --name=studentEntries
```

It is imported in the corresponding places, but I get the following error:

```
1.If 'student-entries' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
of this module.
2. If 'student-entries' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' 
to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

The code in app.module.ts is similar to:

```
@NgModule({
   imports: []
   declarations: [StudentEntries],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: You can't put a component into `imports` array. Could you remove it and try again?

Comment: It is not in imports, it was an error passing it to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If '<selector>' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43937387/if-selector-is-an-angular-component-then-verify-that-it-is-part-of-this-mod)

Comment: And the component you have devclared really has the selector "student-entries"?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly that.